# Google Analytics page view

Tags: google-analytics, pageviews

I'm trying to get the pageview number for the a particular page,

but I see two page view entry

I have:

/page  ==> 100 page view

/page/ ==> 50 page view

The two pages are exactly the same page, but why does it have two entries?

Is the GA double counting, so instead of 150 views, I actually only get 100 view?

How do I combine the two entries?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter to the Google Analytics View to join then.

Go to the Admin section > View column > Filters.

Add Filter > Name it the way you want > Custom > Check "Advanced" option.

Select the field Request URI, in field A put the value "^(/.*)/$".
In field B put "-".
In the Output "$A1", just like the image below.

[image]

Hope I've helped you.

Regards, 
Vítor Capretz

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad it wasn't double counting, so the numbers can be added together?

Comment: Yes! It usually happens with index pages when navigating trought the website

Answer (score 0):

Good idea for your SEO and Google Analytics is to set-up redirects from **page** to **page/** (or vice versa). I.e. you need to set-up rule for canonical urls: either with slash, or without slash. And stick with the rule.